# Controlling Excel and TXT Files through ACCESS VBA

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I am trying to open an EXCEL file, edit it, and then save it as a .txt file through ACCESS VBA. Here is the code that I currently have:

```
Set xls = New Excel.Application
Set xlbook = xls.Workbooks.Open(xlpath, ReadOnly:=True)
Set xlsheet = xlbook.Sheets("Extract")
xlsheet.Rows(1).EntireRow.Delete
xlsheet.Range("A1:" & xlsheet.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Address).Sort xlsheet.Range("A1"), xlAscending
xlbook.SaveAs OutputDir & dARR(i) & ".txt", xlText
Close xlbook
xls.Workbooks(1).Close
```

The problem that I am having is that I am unable to close the .txt or excel file. The bottom two lines of the code error out.

Comment: Just use `xlbook.Close True`.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I had been doing xlbook.close; however that errorred out, so I switched to close xlbook. The xls.workbooks(1).close true; however does not work. Xlbook now refers to the .txt fie so I am not sure how to close out of the excel file.

Comment: So, is it working for you with true at end?

Comment: Ignore my last comment. Everythings works not with the true. Thank you.

Comment: @Derek Please add how you could solve the problem in the answer below. This will help other users to solve the same problems when they visit a Question with a answer.